# Search multiple keywords in Opencart module

Tags: php, oop, opencart

I intend to use a search with multiple keywords. I made ​​a module named "residev". This module will find the appropriate data from a lot of keywords entered. I have successfully if using only 1 keyword, but for many keywords am having errors.

the focus is the code below, I changed the code OpenCart arrangement in taking such a database so. It's also a lot of code to search keywords.

```
$noresinya = mysql_real_escape_string($this->request->get['nomor_resi']);
            $hasil = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_order WHERE nomor_resi LIKE '%".$noresinya."%'");
            $pisah_kata = explode(",", $noresinya);
            $produk = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oc_order_product where order_id = ".$hasil['order_id']."");
            foreach($pisah_kata as $p){
                $hasil .= " OR nomor_resi LIKE '%$p%' ";
            }
            while($hasilnya = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){ // and other codes
```

below is the complete code of the controller 'residev'

http://pastebin.com/uxVm6FTe

below is the complete code of the model 'residev'

http://pastebin.com/FMAymqHW

In View, just a form for searching. Anyone can find the sollution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow MVC-L (Model View Controller - Language) code structure. So, I follow by this rule.. Model class, use `IN` instead of `OR` parts and explode logics. Your query should like that:

`WHERE categories IN ("red", "blue", "green")`

And you can escape with this method in model class which is very pretty and easy:

`$this->db->escape('$this->request->get['nomor_resi']')`

And try to use single query. You can use JOIN's.